# Invalid data for numeric variable in line xxx

Tags: sas

I am trying to import a data sheet in SAS using the Proc Import function. However, the import is unsuccessfull due to invalid data in two numeric variables (SAMPLE_D and SAMPLE_T). How do I change this so I can import my data? I still want the variables to be numeric but this is pretty much a hard stop. First my code:

````
/* Source File: LAB_MICRO.csv */
/* Source Path: /sasfolders/user/mhau0061 */
/* Code generated on: 20/02/22 17.25 */

%web_drop_table(WORK.LAB_CULT);


FILENAME REFFILE '/sasfolders/user/mhau0061/LAB_MICRO.csv';

PROC IMPORT DATAFILE=REFFILE
    DBMS=DLM
    OUT=WORK.LAB_CULT;
    DELIMITER=";";
    GETNAMES=YES;
    GUESSINGROWS=15000;
RUN;

PROC CONTENTS DATA=WORK.LAB_CULT; RUN;


%web_open_table(WORK.LAB_CULT); ```

and it gives me the following error message in the log:

WARNING: Limit set by ERRORS= option reached.  Further errors of this type will not be printed.
NOTE: Invalid data for SAMPLE_D in line 18 159-162.
 NOTE: Invalid data for SAMPLE_D in line 18 159-162.
x many.

I have tried to change the guessing rows to max but it still gives errors. What should I do?
````

Comment: Why are you using PROC IMPORT to guess what is in the file? Why not just write your own data step to read the file?  Show the first 18 lines of the text file you are reading to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own data step step to read the file. Then you can read any problem variables as text.

If you have documentation on the lengths of the fields in the file then use those, otherwise you could just round up little from what PROC IMPORT was able to guess from looking at this one version of the file.

```
data lab_micrp;
  infile REFFILE dsd dlm=';' truncover firstobs=2 ;
  length 
    PATIENT    $300
    LAB_INT_ID $40
    SRC        $10
    SAMPLE_D   $10
    SAMPLE_T   $20
    SAMPLE_MAT $50
    REF_DEPARTM $50
    INV_EXAM_TYPE $20
    COM_GRP       $200
    SAMPLE_LOC $30
    INV_EXAM   $50
    CLIN_INF   $80
    MIC_RES    $200
    REF_HOSP   $50
    SAMPLE_LAB_INT_ID $40 
  ;
  input patient -- sample_lab_int_id;
run;
```

Once you have the data in a dataset you can use SAS to look a the values and see if you need to modify the step that reads the values. Or add steps to convert the text read into other types of variables.